# Merge multiple .so shared libraries

Tags: c, linux, unix, gcc, shared-libraries

Say I have a.so and b.so.
Can I produce c.so as a single shared library with all the functions exported by a and b, of course resolving all intra-dependencies (i.e. all functions of b.so called by a.so and the other way around)?

I tried

```
gcc -shared -Wl,soname,c.so -o c.so a.so b.so
```

but it doesn't work.

Same goes if I archive a.o and b.o in a.a and b.a (which shouldn't modify a.o and b.o), and do

```
gcc -shared -Wl,soname,c.so -o c.so a.a b.a
```

Thanks

Comment: In the end I resorted to use a library script with a GROUP which allows me to show all the small libraries as a single one, but one software could just link to the right "sub"-library.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Merging multiple shared libraries into one is indeed practically impossible on all UNIXen, except AIX: the linker considers the .so a "final" product.

But merging archives into .so should not be a problem:

```
gcc -shared -o c.so -Wl,--whole-archive a.a b.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

Comment: Does the order of the archives matter here? If I have a bunch of .a files, can I use *.a?

Comment: @Raj No, the order doesn't matter -- they all will be included in their entirety. If you don't have any symbol redefinitions in your `*.a`, then `*.a` will just work (TM).

Comment: @EmployedRussian: I have tried the above command with g++, i,e g++ -shared -o c.so -Wl,--whole-archive a.a b.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive   

I got the following error: 
/usr/bin/ld: unrecognized option '-plugin'
/usr/bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

What changes do I need to do?

Answer (score 11):

In practice it is not possible.

From linker point of view, a SO library is a final product that does not contain relocation information required for linking.

If you have access to either source or object files for both libraries, it is straightforward to compile/link a combined SO from them.

Comment: "if you have access to either source or object files for both libraries, it is straightforward to compile/link a combined SO from them." --- How do I do this ? Specifically, on Android platform.