# Combining third-party static libraries into a stand-alone static library with cmake?

Tags: c++, linker, cmake, static-linking

So I have, say, `libA.a libB.a libC.a libD.so` and some code that is linked into `libPack.a`. Later on, I'll create `libFinal.so` that will link to libPack.a and the libFinal.so is finally used on a executable.

When the linker creates the static library, I believe every dynamic library is resolved and included at compile time within the static library. Does it do that as well for (`-fPIC`) third party static libraries?

How can I combine a bunch of static libraries and shared libraries into one huge stand-alone `libFinal.so` library using CMake? If that's not possible, does it mean I have to provide all the lib dependences to the client?

I've managed to get the executable working with a dummy library without dependencies (without `libA...D`), but I get undefined symbols for third-party libraries when I use a libPack.a linked to `libA..D`. My guess is that static libraries are not shipped within `libPack.a`, but I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: A static library is not linked, think of it as a `zip` of object files.  Linking only occurs on executables and shared libraries.

Comment: what i think is the *undefined symbol* is from `libD.so` or other 3rd party library on your system

Answer (score 0):

Following answers might be useful:
[How to combine several C/C++ libraries into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128/how-to-combine-several-c-c-libraries-into-one)
and
[Merge multiple .so shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915128/merge-multiple-so-shared-libraries)

If this meets your needs, you could configure the CMake script to add to the project a pre-link event that combines the libraries into libFinal.so and furhter link libFinal.so to the executable.