# Statically link multiple libraries into one .so

Tags: c, gcc

I've got a project `foo` which depends upon `a`, which in turn depends upon `b`, in turn depends upon `c`. My build script pull/`configure`/`make`'s the three dependencies from source in the correct order, and they compile fine.

Right now, to distribute `foo.so`, I also need to distribute all of its dependencies (`a.so`, `b.so`, and `c.so`) alongside. I want to build a `foo.so` containing all the objects of both `foo` and all of its dependencies; that way I can distribute a single library.

`a`, `b`, and `c` all use autotools, and generate the associated *.o files in the src/ directory, as well as a .libs/ directory containing the usual smattering of *.ar, *.lo, *.lai, and *.so files, all valid. Right now, I'm using this set of gcc flags to build my `foo.so`:

```
gcc -shared ./my/src/*.c \
    -I./a/include -I./b/include -I./c/include \
    -L ./a/.libs -L./b/.libs -L./c/.libs \
    -la -lb -lc \
    -o ./foo.so \
    -w -fPIC -m64 \
    -std=c99
```

(note that "-la -lb -lc" are just "-l" flags for each dependency, i'm not just messing up the flags).

Using `readelf -d` on the resultant `foo.so` indeed shows that it has a dependency on `a`. Given that I've got all the build files for all the dependencies, it really feels like I'm just missing some flag for "include this path when looking for *.o files to link".

I've tried a variety of things, and honestly can't even remember the different errors and conditions that led to them. The most promising lead was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/924181/860453), but after removing my "-l" lines in favor of "-Wl,--whole-archive" lines, I get this error (note that "a.a" is just the *.a for `a`):

```
/usr/bin/ld: ./a/.libs/a.a(bands.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
./a/.libs/a.a(bands.o): error adding symbols: Bad value
```

Which makes no sense to me, since those files need to be PIC in order to build them into a *.so, right? The build process for these dependencies makes a *.so.

I'm on Mint Linux, if it matters.

Comment: If you have `.la` files, use `libtool` to handle the [linking](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/libtool.html#Linking-libraries). e.g., `libtool --mode=link gcc -o foo.la ./my/src/*.lo ./a/a.la ./b/b.la ./c/c.la` - requiring the source objects to be built with `libtool --mode=compile gcc <cflags> -c file.c`

Answer (score 3):

The error message is very clear on what needs to be done.

```
/usr/bin/ld: ./a/.libs/a.a(bands.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against
`.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

./a/.libs/a.a(bands.o): error adding symbols: Bad value
```

The object code that we are part of the static libraries cannot be put in a shared library unless they are compiled with the `-fPIC` option.

Comment: But doesn't it already have to have been compiled as PIC, since the autotools/make process creates an `a.so`?

Comment: I don't know how the autotools and make have been set up. They clearly aren't adding `-fPIC` to the compiler when compiling the files before adding the resulting object files to the static library(ies).

Answer (score 1):

With help from the answerers here, I was able to get a working solution. I had fundamentally misunderstood  that autotools generates two sets of *.o files, one which is PIC, one which isn't. The location for each one is in the *.lo file. My dependencies (`a`, `b`, and `c`) were all built with autotools, and i needed to link against the PIC versions, not the combined static *.a version.

I also needed to split my build process into two parts with libtool. A compile phase just to build my code, and the linker phase that looked at the PIC versions of the dependencies.

I didn't end up with a pretty script, but if anyone hits the same scenario, my ugly gcc lines look like. Hopefully it will be a jumping point to something less... awful than what I came up with.

```
find ./my/src -name "*.c" -exec \
libtool --mode=compile gcc -c -O -g \
    -I./a/include -I./b/include -I./c/include \
    -L./a/.libs/*.lo -L./b/.libs/*.lo -L./c/.libs/*.lo \
    -la -lb -lc \
    -w -m64 \
    -std=c99 \
    {} \;

gcc \
    -g -O -w -fPIC -m64 -std=c99 -shared \
    -o ./foo.so \
    $(find . -wholename "*.libs/*.o");
```