# How to wrap std::vector of custom structure with ffi?

Tags: c++, ruby, vector, ffi

I am trying to create a Ruby wrapper for dynamic *.so library which deals with image processing. One of the functions `convert_x_to_z` has a custom typedef input parameter. How can I pass in the vector of `A` objects if I mapped the `A` struct

```
typedef struct image {
    uint16_t image_width;
    uint16_t image_height;
    uint16_t image_depth;
    uint8_t* data;
} A;
```

into a `FFI:Structure` like this

```
 class A  < FFI::Struct
    layout :image_width , :int,
           :image_height, :int,
           :image_depth, :int,
           :data, :pointer
  end
```

Suppose I have a variable `single` which is a instance of class A. How can I wrap this into an array of class B, which will represent the vector/array of classes `A` and pass it as a parameter `const B &x` to the function `int32_t convert_x_to_z`?

```
int32_t convert_x_to_z(
    const B &x,
    uint32_t &t,
    uint8_t* z);
```

This is the `B` vector or array struct of `A` class.

```
typedef std::vector<A> B;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it this way:

```
int32_t convert_x_to_z_aux(const A &a, uint32_t &t, uint8_t* z) {
    std::vector<A> b(1, a); // create a vector with 1 element
    return convert_x_to_z(b, t, z);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I do not have an access to the C++ code, it is compiled dynamic library, to which I do not have source files. So this won't really work. I need to do this on a Ruby level.

Comment: @adamliesko, Just create your own library on top of the legacy one.

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you point me into some kind of guide/tutorial how could I do that? Isn't this http://stackoverflow.com/a/915181/1212336 and obstacle here (if I do not have the source files)?

Comment: Far too late to be useful to you, but in observance of [Cunningham's Law](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cunningham%27s_Law): merging objects is hard because you don't need to do it. I have zero experience with Ruby FFI, but I would try either wrapping the library's functions (you might even be able to "statically link" the image lib to end up with a single `.so` again) or loading [both `.so`s](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/Using-Multiple-and-Alternate-Libraries#using-three-libraries) and using whatever ruby FFI calls its opaque pointer type to pass the image output to `convert_x_to_z_aux`.