# Undefined symbols while loading shared object in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, dynamic-linking

I want to load xxx.so using `dlopen()`, while loading It throws an error:

> "Undefined Symbol "Function Name"

The Function is defined in yyy.so. While compiling I have linked yyy.so with xx.so

**Eg:

```
g++34 -shared -o xxx.so -L/(lib path) -lyy**
```

I have tried  "-u" option with function name for force linking. But not able linked.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915128/merge-multiple-so-shared-libraries

Comment: xx.so is not a static library and so does not get meshed into yyy.so, To use yyy.so you will also need to have xx.so mapped.

Comment: Is it possible you are trying to link C++ and C?  They have different linkages (which mean they have different names).  You may have to use "extern C { ... }"  or compile the other .so with g++ (if you control that).