# How to link .so library properly in C++?

Tags: linux, c++11, grpc, dynamic-linking, dlopen

I have project structure like this,

```
a.pb.h          --- includes -->    protobuf.h
b.grpc.pb.h     --- includes -->    a.pb.h & grpcpp.h
```

Also there are `a.pb.cc` and `b.grpc.cc` files.

A C++ wrapper with *extern C* which is `wrapper.cc` and `wrapper.h` which includes `b.grpc.pb.h` and `grpcpp.h`.
The function inside *extern C* is `char* helloWorld(const char*, const char*, const char*);`

Creating `.o` of `a.pb.h` and `b.grpc.pb.h`:

```
g++ -fpic -std=c++11 `pkg-config --cflags protobuf grpc`  -c -o a.pb.o a.pb.cc
g++ -fpic -std=c++11 `pkg-config --cflags protobuf grpc`  -c -o b.grpc.pb.o b.grpc.pb.cc
```

Steps to create `libcombined.so`:

The `grpc` and `protobuf` so are already provided under `/usr/local/lib`.
First created `.so` of `a.pb.o` and `b.grpc.pb.o` to compile wrapper file as:

```
g++ -shared -o libcombined.so *.o
```

Compiled wrapper as:

```
g++ -fpic wrapper.cc -l:./libcombined.so -c -o wrapper.o -std=c++11
```

`.so` of `a.pb.o`, `b.grpc.pb.o` and `wrapper.o` as `libcombined.so`:

```
g++ -shared -o libcombinedwrapper.so *.o
```

Compiled main.c as:

```
gcc main.c -l:./libcombinedwrapper.so -o main -ldl
```

I am calling `helloWorld` from my `main.c` file which is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(){
    char* (*fn)(const char*,const char*,const char*);
    void *handle  = dlopen("path_to/libcombined.so",RTLD_NOW);
    if(handle==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", dlerror());
    }
    fn = (char* (*)(const char*,const char*,const char*))dlsym(handle, "helloWorld");
    if (!fn) {
        /* no such symbol */
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", dlerror());
        dlclose(handle);
        return 0;
    }
    char* msg = fn("asd","asdas","asdasd");
    printf("%s",msg);
    return 0;
}
```

Error after executing: `./main`

```
Error: path_to/libcombinedwrapper.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf2io20ZeroCopyOutputStream15WriteAliasedRawEPKvi
Error: ./main: undefined symbol: helloWorld
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The first above error is from symbol from `protobuf.h` file.

Can someone please suggest what I am doing wrong while linking or is there something I am doing wrong in `main.c` file?

Comment: Why tag C++ and C++11 if you ask question about C?

Comment: Show *all* the compilation commands, including the one for `main.c` (it might need `-rdynamic`). And your question is probably OS specific (perhaps a `linux` tag is missing). BTW, you could link more libraries into `libcombined.so`

Comment: Show all command lines you use to build.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I can't link more libraries like protobuf and grpc as they are already provided as .so in /usr/local/lib.

Comment: You don't link any library inside `libcombined.so` and perhaps you should (link the grpc library into it)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch it will increase the library size even if I pass the library during the compilation as 
`gcc main.c -l:./libcombinedwrapper.so -l:/usr/local/lib/libgrpc.so -l:/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so -o main -ldl` 
It doesnot work.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19424604/841108) answer. Doing the same won't increase a lot your `libcombined.so`. I can't understand why you need a wrapper, and your question should give the code of `wrapper.cc`. Please provide some [MCVE] in your question

Comment: I think he needs a wrapper since grpc functions are written in C++.

Comment: Grpc library is in c++ and I need to call those function from my C code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch [link]https://stackoverflow.com/a/924181 refer this link. Combining already .so's is not possible on Unix.

Comment: Have you ever considered to use [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Simple-Makefile)?

Comment: @KaiserKatze how will make help with dynamic library linking?

Answer (score 0):

> `g++ -shared -o libcombined.so *.o`

You need to also link in *all* dependencies of the objects (`libgrpc` here).

You can add `-Wl,--no-allow-shlib-undefined` to verify that `libcombined.so` is linking *everything it needs*.

P.S. To avoid core dump, you should `exit` or `return` once `dlopen` fails.

P.P.S. It is generally a very bad idea(TM) to link `*.o`. Use proper `Makefile` to avoid unnecessary compilations and explicitly list objects that you are intending to put into `libcombined.so`.