# Create a plugin from multiple files from different directories

Tags: go, go-build

Following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/learning-the-go-programming-language/writing-modular-go-programs-with-plugins-ec46381ee1a9) and the github [repo](https://github.com/vladimirvivien/go-plugin-example) I understood the use of plugins.

The tutorial compiles each file separately into so files.

```
go build -buildmode=plugin -o eng/eng.so eng/greeter.go
go build -buildmode=plugin -o chi/chi.so chi/greeter.go
```

How can I merge two files into a single .so file? I tried following command by separating files through space

```
go build -buildmode=plugin -o bin/langs.so src/test/eng/greeter.go src/test/chi/greeter.go
```

The error:

> named files must all be in one directory; have src/test/eng/ and
>   src/test/chi/

The idea is to have a single .so files from different packages.

**Edit: I guess the follow up question would be how to combine all `.so` files into one archive if one has several packages of a library and go only allows one `.so` file per package.**

Answer (score 1):

You can't put them in different folders because they should have same package name (main). But you can put them in different files like this :

file1:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type greeting_en string

func (g greeting_en) Greet() {
    fmt.Println("Hello Universe")
}


var GreeterEn greeting_en
```

file2:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type greeting_chi string


func (g greeting_chi) Greet() {
    fmt.Println("你好宇宙")
}


var GreeterChi greeting_chi
```

compile them like this :

```
go build -buildmode=plugin -o ./langs.go
```

And load langs like this :

```
mod = "./langs.so"
plug, _ := plugin.Open(mod)
EnglishGreeter,_ := plug.Lookup("GreeterEn")
ChineseGreeter,_ := plug.Lookup("GreeterChi")
```

Comment: so essentially it's one `so` file per package, so how's it done in real life? I've a library of multiple packages, that means I'll be distributing several `so` files for my project? is there an archive that allows to combine all so files in a package?

Comment: No there is no such thing you have to combine them yourself

Comment: is this applicable -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915128/merge-multiple-so-shared-libraries