# Why am I getting "undefined symbol" when I link my static library in my C program?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, ld, dynamic-linking

I'm trying to create a static library to allow me to use a C++ API in my C program. To get started, I'm trying to call an API function called `APIName::Api_init()`; So far, I have created a "wrapper" library which has the following:

c_api.h:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define EXTERNC extern "C"
#else
#define EXTERNC
#endif
EXTERNC int apiname_api_init(char const * user_app_name);
EXTERNC void apiname_api_shutdown();

#undef EXTERNC
```

c_api.cpp:

```
#include "c_api.h"
#include "../include/apiname/api.h"   // Link to header files from API provider
int apiname_api_init(char const * user_app_name) {
        return to_return_code(APIName::Api_init(user_app_name));
}

void apiname_api_shutdown() {
        return APIName::api_shutdown();
}
```

I then compile this into an object file called apiwrapper.o using the following command:

```
g++  -L../include/libs -lapinameapi  -shared -fPIC -c -D_LINUX_X86_64 -lpthread -lz -lm -lcrypto -lbz2 -I../include -DPROVIDE_LOG_UTILITIES -DTARGET_PLATFORM_LINUX  c_api.cpp -o lapiwrapper.o -lrt
```

where `apinameapi` is the shared library from the API provider.  This works fine.  I then generate the library file using:

```
ar rc libapiwrapper.a apiwrapper.o
```

Again, this is fine.

Now I create my C file (mycode.c), which contains:

```
#include "mycode.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <Windows.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
int connectToApi() {

  // Init API
  rc = apiname_api_init("programname");

}
```

The header file mycode.h contains:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "c_api.h"
```

(obviously there's other stuff as well, but I've left it out for brevity).

So, I compile my main program using:

```
gcc  -Linclude/libs -lapiwrapper  -shared -DKXVER=3 -fPIC -D_LINUX_X86_64 -lpthread -lz -lm -lcrypto -lbz2 -Iinclude -DPROVIDE_LOG_UTILITIES -DTARGET_PLATFORM_LINUX  src/mycode.c -o lib/mycode.so -lrt -Wno-discarded-qualifiers -Wno-incompatible-pointer-types
```

which is also fine. Then, I run the program (this particular file gets loaded by another piece of code), and I get

`undefined symbol: apiname_api_init`

It seems that it's not finding the function in the library file.  Where am I going wrong? This is my first time building a library, so it's probably something fairly basic.

EDIT: I think the issue may be coming from the fact that the final compilation (which creates mycode.so) is producing a shared object file, and I need that to run on its own (without needing my generated library file to be present as well).  I have to run the final object from another program, so it needs to be standalone. Is there a way I can link it to "bundle" everything together into one final so file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Comment: I tried changing the order, but it didn't seem to make any difference.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Sharon It is an interesting question to tinker on. But can you give clarity on this particular line "Then, I run the program". There is no main() function in any code you posted. The final output is also ``.so`` file, where are you using it ?

Comment: @MohithReddy it is called from another file in another language.  So, I want to generate mycode.so as a shared object, and then from the other code (in a different, specialist language) can import the C object and run it. Does that make sense? So it will call something like mycode.connectToApi().

Answer (score 1):

The command `ar rc libapiwrapper.a apiwrapper.o` creates a static library. If you link with that you will also need to link in its dependancies.
What you need is to create a shared library (`.so` file).
You'll probably need someting like this (I have split the compile and link steps in idividual commands):

```
g++ -lapinameapi -c -D_LINUX_X86_64 -I../include -DPROVIDE_LOG_UTILITIES -DTARGET_PLATFORM_LINUX c_api.cpp -o lapiwrapper.o
g++ -shared -fPIC -o libapiwrapper.so lapiwrapper.o -L../include/libs -lpthread -lz -lm -lcrypto -lbz2 -lrt
```

Finally it's just a matter of linking the executable with this shared library instead of the static library.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the problem using `libssl` and `libcrypto`. So in my case, I need to produce an `api_wrapper` which uses the functions of `libssl` and `libcrypto` and it should be standalone. But unfortunately, as you were asking in the EDIT, two or more shared libraries cannot be bundled together. Please refer to this link [Merge multiple .so shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915128/merge-multiple-so-shared-libraries). If your so-called `different, specialist language` is able to load a static library as well, then you can proceed as follows.

My `api_wrappers`

`apiconnect.c`

```
#include "apiconnect.h"
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

int api_connect()
{
        SSL_library_init();
        OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
        SSL_load_error_strings();

        return 0;
}
```

`apiconnect.h`

```
int api_connect();
```

- How I produced `libapi.a`

As my code is dependent on `libssl` and `libcrypto`, I started collecting their static versions from `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. Then I extracted the contents of `libssl.a` and `libcrypto.a` using `ar x library`. I got around `700` object files. `apiconnect.c` is compiled to produce `apiconnect.o` and added to extracted object files. Then I packed all of them together to produce `libapi.a`. Below shows my terminal session:

```
root@kali:/tmp/apiconnect# ls 
apiconnect.c  apiconnect.h  libapi
root@kali:/tmp/apiconnect# cd libapi/
root@kali:/tmp/apiconnect/libapi# cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a .
root@kali:/tmp/apiconnect/libapi# ar x libssl.a 
root@kali:/tmp/apiconnect/libapi# ar x libcrypto.a 
root@kali:/tmp/apiconnect/libapi# ls | wc -l 
702
root@kali:/tmp/apiconnect/libapi# cd ..
root@kali:/tmp/apiconnect# gcc -c apiconnect.c 
root@kali:/tmp/apiconnect# ls 
apiconnect.c  apiconnect.h  apiconnect.o  libapi
root@kali:/tmp/apiconnect# cp apiconnect.o libapi/
root@kali:/tmp/apiconnect# cd libapi/
root@kali:/tmp/apiconnect/libapi# ls *.a
libcrypto.a  libssl.a
root@kali:/tmp/apiconnect/libapi# rm *.a
root@kali:/tmp/apiconnect/libapi# ar rc libapi.a *
root@kali:/tmp/apiconnect/libapi# ls libapi.a
libapi.a
```

- Testing

Since I don't know `different, specialist language` and I don't have it, for testing purposes I moved `libapi.a` and `apiconnect.h` to another system which does not have `libssl` or `libcrypto` installed. I tried to compile a test program which calls `api_connect()`.

Test Program:

```
#include "apiconnect.h"

int main()
{
   api_connect();
   return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
jhansi@poseidon:/tmp/apitesting$ ls 
apiconnect.h  libapi.a  test.c
jhansi@poseidon:/tmp/apitesting$ cat test.c 
#include "apiconnect.h"

int main()
{
api_connect();
return 0;
}
jhansi@poseidon:/tmp/apitesting$ gcc -L./ test.c -lapi
.//libapi.a(threads_pthread.o): In function `CRYPTO_THREAD_lock_new':
(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_init'
.//libapi.a(threads_pthread.o): In function `CRYPTO_THREAD_read_lock':
(.text+0x85): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_rdlock'
.//libapi.a(threads_pthread.o): In function `CRYPTO_THREAD_write_lock':
(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_wrlock'
.//libapi.a(threads_pthread.o): In function `CRYPTO_THREAD_unlock':
(.text+0xc5): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_unlock'
.//libapi.a(threads_pthread.o): In function `CRYPTO_THREAD_lock_free':
(.text+0xea): undefined reference to `pthread_rwlock_destroy'
.//libapi.a(threads_pthread.o): In function `CRYPTO_THREAD_run_once':
(.text+0x115): undefined reference to `pthread_once'
.//libapi.a(threads_pthread.o): In function `CRYPTO_THREAD_init_local':
(.text+0x135): undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
.//libapi.a(threads_pthread.o): In function `CRYPTO_THREAD_set_local':
(.text+0x167): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
.//libapi.a(threads_pthread.o): In function `CRYPTO_THREAD_cleanup_local':
(.text+0x187): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
.//libapi.a(threads_pthread.o): In function `openssl_init_fork_handlers':
(.text+0x1e3): undefined reference to `pthread_once'
.//libapi.a(threads_pthread.o): In function `fork_once_func':
(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `pthread_atfork'
.//libapi.a(threads_pthread.o): In function `CRYPTO_THREAD_get_local':
(.text+0x153): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
.//libapi.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_globallookup':
(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `dlopen'
(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `dlsym'
(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `dlclose'
.//libapi.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_bind_func':
(.text+0x1a7): undefined reference to `dlsym'
(.text+0x272): undefined reference to `dlerror'
.//libapi.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_load':
(.text+0x2e1): undefined reference to `dlopen'
(.text+0x359): undefined reference to `dlclose'
(.text+0x395): undefined reference to `dlerror'
.//libapi.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_pathbyaddr':
(.text+0x452): undefined reference to `dladdr'
(.text+0x4c7): undefined reference to `dlerror'
.//libapi.a(dso_dlfcn.o): In function `dlfcn_unload':
(.text+0x6a4): undefined reference to `dlclose'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But unfortunately, it turns out to be that the object files we included are dependent on `libpthread` and `libdl`, and after including them in the compilation, I was successful to compile and run the program without errors.

```
jhansi@poseidon:/tmp/apitesting$ ls 
apiconnect.h  libapi.a  test.c
jhansi@poseidon:/tmp/apitesting$ gcc -L./ test.c  -lapi -lpthread -ldl
jhansi@poseidon:/tmp/apitesting$ ls 
a.out  apiconnect.h  libapi.a  test.c
jhansi@poseidon:/tmp/apitesting$ ldd a.out 
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffedd2d7000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd3d0f30000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd3d0d2c000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd3d093b000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd3d1633000)
jhansi@poseidon:/tmp/apitesting$ ./a.out 
jhansi@poseidon:/tmp/apitesting$
```

From the output of `ldd a.out`, it is evident that our executable is not dependent on either of `libssl` and `libcrypto`, and of course it is not dependent on `libapi.a` since it is statically linked. But it is dependent `libpthread.so` and `libdl.so`, So if I were you, I would be loading `libpthread.so` and `libdl.so` along with `libapi.a`

I know, what is wrote is specific to `libssl` and `libcrypto`, but I hope you will find some luck with the libraries you are trying. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to extern "C" your CPP file the same way you did your header; otherwise the method names will be mangled in the object.

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int apiname_api_init(char const * user_app_name) {
        return to_return_code(APIName::Api_init(user_app_name));
}

void apiname_api_shutdown() {
        return APIName::api_shutdown();
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```