# Custom CMake library - What have I done wrong?

Tags: c++, cmake, undefined-reference

I am trying to install a custom library with CMake.

It consists of 2 'sub-libraries' and a main header file which includes the 'sub-libraries'.

I think it installs okay (The output looks like this:)

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/pi/Desktop/Projects/MaxLib/build
[ 20%] Building CXX object Geom/CMakeFiles/Geom.dir/Geom.cpp.o
[ 40%] Linking CXX shared library libGeom.so
[ 40%] Built target Geom
[ 60%] Building CXX object File/CMakeFiles/File.dir/File.cpp.o
[ 80%] Linking CXX shared library libFile.so
[ 80%] Built target File
[100%] Built target MaxLib
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Debug"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/libMaxLib.a
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/MaxLib.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/MaxLib/File.h
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/MaxLib/Geom.h
```

However, when I try to compile a program using it, I receive a number of "undefined reference to" errors. Where have I gone wrong?

The Main Header looks like:

```
#include "MaxLib/File.h"
#include "MaxLib/Geom.h"
```

It's CMakefile looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(MaxLib)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/MaxLib.h"
)

add_subdirectory(File)
add_subdirectory(Geom)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} File)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Geom)

# Install Library
install (TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)

# Install Main Header File
INSTALL(FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/MaxLib.h" DESTINATION include) # 
INSTALL(FILES ...) or install(DIRECTORY ...) 

# Build list of header files to install from other directorys. Root == "."
set(HEADER_DIRS "File" "Geom")
## Add Source Files from the other directories
foreach(DIR ${HEADER_DIRS})
    # Find all source files & append to list
    if(DIR STREQUAL ".")
        file(GLOB HEADER_FILES_IN_FOLDER *.h)
    else()
        file(GLOB HEADER_FILES_IN_FOLDER ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${DIR}/*.h)
    endif()
    list(APPEND HEADER_FILES ${HEADER_FILES_IN_FOLDER})
endforeach()
# Install Header files
INSTALL(FILES ${HEADER_FILES} DESTINATION include/${PROJECT_NAME}) # INSTALL(FILES ...) or install(DIRECTORY ...) 

target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -g) 
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

The 'sub-libraries's CMakefiles look like this:

```
project(Geom)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Geom.cpp
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

I am trying to include the library like this:

```
#include <MaxLib.h>
```

And I am adding -lMaxLib to its makefile

**Edit:**

A basic program like this:

```
#include <MaxLib.h>

int main() {
    float y1 = MaxLib::Geom::CleanAngle(7654);
}
```

Will produce the undefined reference error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libFile.so, needed by //usr/local/lib/libMaxLib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link) // This shows when add_library marked SHARED
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libGeom.so, needed by //usr/local/lib/libMaxLib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link) // This shows when add_library marked SHARED
/home/pi/Desktop/Projects/TestProgram/main.cpp:43: undefined reference to `MaxLib::Geom::CleanAngle(double)'
```

Comment: Despite you link MaxLib library with `Geom` and `File`, those libraries are NOT incorporated into MaxLib. Also, as MaxLib is a **static** library (`.a`), it doesn't remember linkage with other libraries. So if your program uses functions from Geom, it need to be **explicitly** linked to it, linkage with MaxLib is not sufficient. You may define MaxLib as a **shared** library (using SHARED keyword), so it will remember linkage. But in that case Geom and File should also be installed or somehow accessible when you link and run your program.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have added SHARED to "add_library()" and it now is a ".so" but this doesn't seem to fix it. Is there something else I have missed?

Comment: It depends on what exact "undefined reference to" you got, and where exactly these symbols are defined. Please, add **more details** about your error into the question post: the exact error message, the exact code which defines missed symbols and so on. In the current state we could only **guess** what is your problem. Ideally, we want a [mcve].

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have updated the question. It seems to not find .so files for file and geom (which i have purposely not created), I was hoping that i could have the library static and only require a single MaxLib.so file?

Comment: Have you read my [first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72502782/custom-cmake-library-what-have-i-done-wrong?noredirect=1#comment128077599_72502782) till the end? "But in that case Geom and File should also be installed or somehow accessible when you link and run your program." You cannot incorporate a shared libraries (`Geom` and `File`) into another library.

Comment: Sorry I am new to all this and it didn't really make sense to me before. So are you saying that you cannot have a single .so / .a file which you link to, regardless of whether the sub-libraries are shared or static?

Comment: What I want is a single library I can link to, what is the best way to acheive this?

Comment: You cannot combine **shared** libraries into the single one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915128/merge-multiple-so-shared-libraries. You can combine **static** libraries into the single one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924383/combining-several-static-libraries-into-one-using-cmake. If you don't want `Geom` (and `File`) to be packed into a separate library file, then you could create it as `OBJECT` library, or don't create it at all.