# Cmake include dependencies in library

Tags: c++, cmake, libraries

I'm trying to build a library that includes tesseract and opencv to target other systems. I manage to configure my toolchain and cmake to generate a .so library file in different architectures, but this library is "clean", it's only the code that I defined.
How can I tell CMake that I want to include Tesseract and OpenCV within my built `.so` file to ship only one file as library?

Comment: ***How can I tell cmake I want to include tesseract and opencv within my built .so file to ship only one file as library?*** I am not sure that this is possible.

Comment: Old answer on merging .so files: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915128/merge-multiple-so-shared-libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915128/merge-multiple-so-shared-libraries)

Comment: `How can I tell cmake I want to include tesseract and opencv` Add the sources of these projects and compile.